# Error message-Could not cast value of type 'PFObject' to 'Message'

Tags: swift, parse-platform, error-handling, pfobject

I am trying to query a message table that I created in Parse. However, when querying the table, I get the error "Could not cast value of type 'PFObject' to 'Message'". What does this error mean?

I am getting an error on the line below:

let message = object as! Message

Comment: Also, I have already registered the subclass in the App Delegate so I know this is not the problem

Comment: Ever figure this out?